# Hibernate + PostgreSQL lanza una excepción: JDBC Driver class not found: org.postgresql.Driver

Tags: java, hibernate

Donde ocurre el error es en la siguiente parte.

```
public class NewHibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 
            // config file.
            sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Log the exception. 
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya revisaste si tienes el jar de conexión de postgres?? También falta que pongas el hibernate.cfg.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error no está en el código, sino en tiempo de ejecución del proyecto. Al parecer no has agregado la dependencia de la librería de conexión a Postgres en tiempo de ejecución.

Si estás trabajando con una aplicación de consola, asegúrate de que la librería esté en el classpath al momento de ejecutar tu proyecto.

Si estás trabajando con una aplicación web, la librería debe encontrarse en la carpeta WEB-INF/lib.

Si usas alguna herramienta de administración del proyecto como maven, gradle u otro, te recomiendo comprobar que tengas la dependencia a la librería.

Ejemplo en maven:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: no creo que exista versión 42 de postgres

Comment: @abrahamhs la versión es del driver, no de la base de datos...

Comment: Si a eso me refiero, yo me conecto con la 9.4 y aunque no están nueva, no creo que hayan saltado a la 42

Comment: @abrahamhs https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/changelog.html En las primeras entradas puedes ver `Version 42.1.4 (2017-08-01)`

Comment: @abrahamhs y sí, saltaron de 9.4.1212 a 42.0.0

Comment: Orale, mira que interesante, eso no lo sabia. Es como del windows 8 al 10. Extraño.